# Oracle COUNT when multiple occurrences on same date

Tags: oracle, count, subquery

Here is what im looking to do.

Count the number of DISTINCT dates when a code occurred more than once for an id.

```
ex:
id,site,code,date
1,01,A,08/20/2012
2,01,A,08/21/2012
1,01,A,08/20/2012
```

Here is what I kind of think it would look like, but obviously wrong...let me know if im not making any sense.  and thanks for looking into this

```
SELECT 
id,
site,
code,
(select count(distinct date)
  from table b
  where code = 'A' and b.id = a.id and count(distinct date) > 2) subquery
from table a


result goal:
1,01,A,1
2,01,A,0 or null
```

Comment: Your output does not match the query you asked for. There is only one distinct date for each ID, but you have different numbers for each row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select "id", "site", "code", 
    count(distinct "date") - 1 as AdditionalDistinctDateCount
from MyTable
group by "id", "site", "code", "date"
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/872a8/5)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with a subquery that aggregates by id and date, and then aggregate again by id:

```
select t.*, tsum.numTwiceOrMore
from (select distinct id, site, code
      from t
     ) t join
     (select id, sum(case when cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numTwiceOrMore
      from (select id, date, count(*) as cnt
            from t
            group by id, date
           ) tsum
      group by id
     ) tsum
     on t.id = tsum.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an aggregate in the `where` clause of the query that calculates it; but that's what the `having` clause is for:

```
SELECT id, site, code,
    (select count(distinct date)
    from table b
    where code = 'A' and b.id = a.id
    having count(distinct date) > 2) subquery
from table a;
```

But don't think this gets what you want anyway; it isn't clear if you want to show the whole row for any `id` (and `site`, and `code`? what criteria are you using?) which has entries with more than one day, or just the count of the dates.

---

OK, think I've figured out what you mean... you only want to show the number of dates **if** a `code` appears more than once for an `id`, presumably on any site? You can use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) for this; using a CTE to get the data you gave as an example:

```
with t as (
    select 1 as id, '01' as site, 'A' as code, date '2012-08-20' dt from dual
    union all select 2, '01', 'A', date '2012-08-21' from dual
    union all select 1, '01', 'A', date '2012-08-20' from dual
)
SELECT distinct id, site, code,
    case when code_count_for_id > 1 then dt_count else null end as dates
FROM (
    SELECT id, site, code, dt,
        count(distinct dt) over (partition by id, code) dt_count,
        count(*) over (partition by id, code) as code_count_for_id
    FROM t
)
ORDER BY id, code;

        ID SI C      DATES
---------- -- - ----------
         1 01 A          1
         2 01 A
```

So in the inner query, `dt_count` is calculated as the number of distinct dates for the `id` and `code` combination, and `code_count_for_id` is calculated as the number of times that combination appears.

Then in the outer query the `case` decides whether to show `dt_count` or `null` depending on the value for `code_count_for_id`.